# FPGrowth algorithm of Spark Mllib stalling on small dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apriori

I am using Spark's Mllib FPGrowth algorithm to generate frequent itemsets. I'm getting the data from redshift and running the code on it. But the code stalls down with a lot of shuffle occurring between workers with the amount of rows being worked on equal to 5000. The code keeps running for 1-2 hours and then I have to kill it manually. I see the line - Asking to fetch output locations for shuffle 1 on the console and nothing else after this. The same code works fine if I increase the dataset to around 50000 rows. I used jstack to check the thread dump and it looks as if there is a deadlock occurring in FPTree when it fetches Iterator.hasnext(). My configuration is 4 workers with 6 executors with 4 cores and 15GB RAM each.

P.S - I know spark is not meant for small datasets but this just for testing purposes but the thread deadlock looks like a bug

Code :

```
val data = data1.map { case Row(city : String, cart : Long, p_list : String) =>
      p_list
    }.rdd
print(data.count)
val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(','))

import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.0001)
  .setNumPartitions(24)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
print(model.freqItemsets.count)

val res = model.generateAssociationRules(0.001)
print(res.count)
```

The code stalls as soon as it reaches the **model.freqItemsets.count** statement.

Thread dump -

```
"Attach Listener" #145 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7508001000 nid=0x4481 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"block-manager-slave-async-thread-pool-6" #144 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7498005000 nid=0x4400 waiting on condition [0x00007f755eee7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000004022797e8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"block-manager-slave-async-thread-pool-5" #143 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7498002800 nid=0x43fe waiting on condition [0x00007f7549dfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000004022797e8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"block-manager-slave-async-thread-pool-4" #142 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74c801f000 nid=0x43fc waiting on condition [0x00007f755c2ac000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000004022797e8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"shuffle-server-1" #58 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7490002000 nid=0x421f runnable [0x00007f7540181000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000404d0c368> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000405ec34f0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000404d0c2d0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Executor task launch worker-3" #140 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74b0004000 nid=0x4183 runnable [0x00007f7540281000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Executor task launch worker-2" #139 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74b0002800 nid=0x4182 runnable [0x00007f7540382000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:216)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Executor task launch worker-1" #138 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74b0001000 nid=0x4181 runnable [0x00007f755e9e1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findOrAddEntry(HashTable.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findOrAddEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.put(HashMap.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.update(HashMap.scala:81)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$add$1.apply(FPTree.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$add$1.apply(FPTree.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree.add(FPTree.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$mllib$fpm$FPTree$$project$1.apply(FPTree.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$mllib$fpm$FPTree$$project$1.apply(FPTree.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree.org$apache$spark$mllib$fpm$FPTree$$project(FPTree.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$extract$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FPTree.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPTree$$anonfun$extract$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FPTree.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.rhs$lzycompute(Iterator.scala:208)
    - locked <0x00000006ce73a440> (a scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.rhs(Iterator.scala:208)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:216)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner" #137 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74dc8c2800 nid=0x417b in Object.wait() [0x00007f755ede6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000408920fd8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000408920fd8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3063)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"shuffle-client-1" #54 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74dc818000 nid=0x417a runnable [0x00007f755efe8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000405ee6968> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000405f108e0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000405ee68d0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"shuffle-client-0" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74dc0dd000 nid=0x4179 runnable [0x00007f755ebe4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000405dc6e08> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000405dc8ef8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000405dc6d60> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"shuffle-client-0" #67 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74dc094000 nid=0x40d1 runnable [0x00007f755e2b7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000405e03260> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000405e03250> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000405e03208> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Executor task launch worker-0" #66 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f74b8002000 nid=0x40d0 runnable [0x00007f755eae2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.next(Iterator.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Mlib FPGrowth job fails with Memory Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690682/spark-mlib-fpgrowth-job-fails-with-memory-error)